# Set a guardian process for the child processes in case parent dies

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

There is a function in QNX procmgr_guardian which sets a child process as the guardian of the other child process in case of the parent's death.
Is there such functionality in Linux too ? How do I implement it in Linux? Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you go back to accept some of the answers you have received in the past...

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get that. What did you mean ?

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry about that. Now I get it ! :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method for monitoring a process that is not your own child. However, there is a hack you can use: Create a FIFO using `pipe()`; ensure that the process to be monitored holds the write end of the pipe (and that it is closed in all other processes). If the process dies, an EOF condition will be signalled in the read end of the pipe (ie, select will indicate a readable condition).

If you want the process to be reparented when its immediate parent dies, you may be able to achieve this with [PID namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/259217/). By arranging for the 'guardian' process to be PID 1 in the PID namespace, it will inherit all orphaned processes in that namespace.

Comment: This is not for monitoring a process which is not a child. "The function procmgr_guardian() allows a daemon process to declare a child process to take over as parent to its children in the event of its death: " It is shown in http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/p/procmgr_guardian.html. I would like to know if a similar function exists in Linux. Or I would like to know if we can change the parent of a child process to another process other than the "init"